# Simplest way to determine if class x is derived from class y? (c#)

Tags: c#, generics, derivative

Is this the simplest way to determine if `foo` is the same or derived from type `T`

```
bool Derives<T>(object foo)
{
  return foo is T;
}
```

and an exact match would be

```
bool ExactMatch<T>(object foo)
{
  return foo.GetType() == typeof(T);
}
```

Comment: Does the answer have to take interfaces into account (e.g. is `ArrayList` derived from `ICollection`? Is `ICollection` derived from `IEnumerable`?)? Does it have to take generics into account? If so, how should it handle the generic type parameters (e.g. is `List<T>` derived from `IList<T>`? Is `List<Giraffe>` derived from `List<Animal>`?)?

Comment: ExactMatch won't work because of `RuntimeType` issues

Comment: RuntimeType issues such as... ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't think of a simpler way :)

(and in 'answer' format, to please the trolls: "Yes")